# Jquery slide toggle not working with multiple classes

Tags: jquery, class, slidetoggle

I previously had this slide toggle working with a once column layout.  Now that I have added multiple divs for a multiple grid layout things are not working correctly.

I would like the hidden content to slide down upon clicking the h1.  I am also trying to get the background of the whole row 100% width of the page to change to the red with the text changing to white.  Currently, I cannot seem to get the  number to change to white and unable to get just one entry to expand with the whole 100% width of the background color changing to red. Can you please help me figure out what's wrong?

Here is the codepen.

http://codepen.io/wragen22/pen/Fjesr

Comment: Can you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?